# How to listen to data changes in Node Js and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So Im designing a MERN project and users create todos and it will be stored in the database.
Im implementing an edit function and I want to see if there is anyway to check if the user has entered a new value and if it has save the todo as a new file.
is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and laughing gas.

Comment: wait why do you need laughing gas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be using [Save/Validate Hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order) from Mongooose for MongoDB

```
schema.pre('validate', function() {
  console.log('this gets printed first');
});
schema.post('validate', function() {
  console.log('this gets printed second');
});
schema.pre('save', function() {
  console.log('this gets printed third');
});
schema.post('save', function() {
  console.log('this gets printed fourth');
});
```